How can I convert 49.999999999993 to 49.99?
I have a decimal number with a lot of digits after the decimal point.
49.999999999999993 which I am interested in trimming it down to 49.99 only.
All of my attempts result in the number being rounded up.
double number = 49.999999999999993;

string str0 = number.ToString("#.##");          // 50.00
string str1 = $"{number:0.00}";                 // 50.00
string str2 = $"{number:#.##}";                 // 50.00
string str3 = Math.Round(number, 2).ToString(); // 50
string str4 = Math.Round(number, 6).ToString(); // 50
string str5 = ((float)number).ToString();       // 50

The only way I can think of right away is to work with slicing substrings.
string str6 = number.ToString().Substring(0, 5);  // 49.99

Is there a better way of trimming off decimal places without rounding up or down?

Did you try Math.floor() ?

@DamolaObaleke - "without rounding up or down?"

Using substring is the best way here imo, since it shows the intent the best.

Even convert is an incorrect word here. OP is not converting anything, the value is still the same

@DarkBee : 49.999999999999993 > 49.99

"without rounding up or down" It does sound like you want to round towards zero - Math.Round(num, 2, System.MidpointRounding.ToZero)

@DarkBee - well if we all knew the exact wording for stuff the world would be a better place, but some lack the knowledge and simply refer to stuff how they believe it makes sense, thats why its better to have a lookup (google search) for all "similar" words they may redirect to the correct wording/functionality

I would never google "convert" to trim or truncate a string

@DarkBee - great for you, I guess - hope you don't reflect yourself to 8 billion people

@DarkBee trimNum = parseFloat(num.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]);
Basically convert it to a string get the first part without the decimal point and the first two values after the decimal point. parse it back as a double or float
